# Triggering or preventing a javascript function if $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] isn't set

Tags: php, javascript, function, isset

This php function currently redirects the user to another page if they aren't logged in

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) == '')){
header("location: login_failed.html");
exit();
}
```

How can I change the function so that instead of redirecting the user it does the following:

- Triggers the javascript function: `loginFailed();`
- Prevents specific iframes which are preloaded from launching *(these require a user to be logged in, and are currently opening as empty iframes if they're not logged in)*. I've included the script for this below. Alternatively, preventing iframes from launching which have a specific class or data-fancybox-type, or those which require `!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'])`.

The functions which I want to trigger/prevent

```
function loginFailed() {
    $().toastmessage('showToast', {
        text: 'Log In Failed<br/><br/>Please check your username and password',
        sticky: false,
        position: 'top-center',
        type: 'message',
        closeText: '',
        close: function () { console.log("toast is closed ...") }
    });
} 
$(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      preload: true,
    });
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

I've tried:

```
echo "<script>loginFailed();</script>";
echo "<script type="text/javascript">loginFailed();</script>";
echo "<script type="text/javascript">loginFailed;</script>";
```

Comment: Can you please post the full javascript? Including the loginFailed() function? Also, WHERE you are echoing the javascript could be effecting your result.

Comment: So the PHP part is in an iframe, but you want it to effect the javascript on the main window?

Comment: Yes, unless I need to go about it another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined @hellohellosharp's suggestion with a solution which was given to me by @willoller for another problem and figured it out :-)

Add this to the php:

```
$logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']));
```

Add this to the javascript:

```
<?php if ($logged_in) : ?>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="iframe1.html"></a>
<?php else : ?>  
     loginFailed();
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm also using this to change the menu options based on whether or not a user's logged in.

Just a reminder - this uses ISSET to determine what javascript should show, but it only changes the user's experience and doesn't provide any security.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to techfoobar's answer...

It is generally a good practice to put your variables from PHP into Javascript (if needed) and letting Javascript handle it, as opposed to echoing different javascript depending on a PHP variable.

Keep in mind that all javascript variables CAN be manipulated by the client.

Try something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) == '')){
$t="no_session";
}
else{
$t="yes_session";
} 

.... 


<script>
var session="<?php echo $t; ?>";

if(session == "no_session")
loginFailed();
</script>
```

Comment: Since the javascript variables can be manipulated by the client, would you suggest using a combination of this and redirect (to prevent specific pages from opening)?

Comment: You should be fine, I was just making sure you weren't using javascript as your only means to protect pages that should only be accessed as users.

Comment: Great :-D Any chance you know how I can also use this to modify the menu items displayed? (That was the next item on my to-do list ;-)

Comment: I'd rather use javascript :-)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work but I'm assuming that it's probably a syntax error on my part. Would you mind taking a look at my code? I posted it on snipt. The php and javascript which are on the page itself are at: http://snipt.org/yps8 and http://snipt.org/ypu1 and the code from auth_loginFailed.php is here: http://snipt.org/ypv6

Comment: It took me longer than I'd expected, but I finally uploaded the pages and all the necessary files :-) The page which launches the iframe is - http://www.click2fit.com/launch_test.html and the iframe itself is - click2fit.com/member_iframe.php

Comment: I also created a set which has a SESS_USER_ID hard-coded so that it can load properly - http://www.click2fit.com/launch_test_set.html and http://www.click2fit.com/member_iframe_set.php

Comment: I was able to figure it out by combining your suggestion with a solution given to me for another problem :-D I couldn't have done it without you!!!

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server side. JavaScript runs on the client side inside the browser. PHP cannot directly invoke JavaScript functions.

PHP can however render JavaScript along with the HTML to the browser so that the browser can in turn run it.

In your particular case, one thing you can do is check for logged-in status via an AJAX call and call the required JS methods on its success callback.

---

**Example:**

For checking the login status:

```
/* JS */
function checkLoginState() {
    $.post('/yourserver.com/isloggedin.php', function(data) {
        if(data != "OK") { //  not logged in

            // call your JS method thats disables stuff etc.
            loginFailed();
        }
    });
}

// Periodically check login state
setInterval(checkLoginState, 10000); // check every 10 seconds, change as needed.

/* PHP - isloggedin.php */
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) == '')){
    echo "NOT OK";
} 
else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: I knew that they run in different areas but I figured that there had to be a way to do it ;-D Would you mind showing me how to do that in AJAX?

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it out right now :-D I'm assuming that this can also be used to modify the menu items displayed? (That was the next item on my to-do list ;-)

Comment: It's echoing "NOT OK", but it isn't triggering loginFailed(). I'm assuming that it's probably a syntax error on my part. Would you mind taking a look at my code? I posted it on snipt. The php and javascript which are on the page itself are at: http://snipt.org/yojh2 and http://snipt.org/yojg4, and the code from isloggedin.php is here: http://snipt.org/yoje9

Comment: I uploaded it to my site thinking it would be easier, but now I'm seeing that it's echo'ing 'OK' even though it's not logged in so I think there's definitely something with the syntax. I'm also wondering if I need to call ajax in some way?  The page which launches the iframe is - www.click2fit.com/launch_test_techfoobar.html and the iframe itself is www.click2fit.com/member_iframe_techfoobar.php