# Trouble when more than one if/else statement required for if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']))

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

This statement works fine if I only use it once, but not when I need to use it several times. I'm curious as to why, but more importantly I would like to know how I can get around that.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'])) { ?>         
<?php }  
else {?>
<?php }
```

I need to change several items on the page depending upon whether or not the user is logged in (menu items, messages to the user, etc.)

Comment: There's absolutely no reason why you shouldn't be able to use this if condition as many times as you like in your script. I can only presume there is something else within the code that is changing the outcome of this condition.

Comment: Going to need more code to diagnose the problem. What you describe shouldn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way around it would be:

```
<?php $logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'])); ?>
```

then

```
<?php if ($logged_in) : ?>
   //show secret stuff
<?php else : ?>
   // show public stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

*BUT*

There is something wrong going on between the first time you access `$_SESSION` and the second time. You are accidentally setting it somewhere (using `=` instead of `==` is an easy way), or you have code with side-effects that is changing it behind the scenes.

Comment: It looks like you were right and the problem was probably a typo on my end :-) I'd like to use your code though to simplify several things and I wanted to clarify 2 things. How would I call $logged_in in a javascript function? (I want to trigger a function if they aren't logged in). Also, I'm trying to determine how secure this method is and if it's ok to use it on every page or if I should continue to redirect users if they're not logged in and only use this on unprotected pages where I want to create a better user experience?

Comment: I'm hoping that this will be a simple fix for another problem that I was dealing with :-) (since I couldn't get the suggestions there to work http://stackoverflow.com/q/13871458/1056713)

Comment: Don't use javascript for that. Use php to decide what javascript to show. Don't use javascript for security.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wanted to be sure. How do I call $logged_in in javascript in order to trigger a javascript function? (It looks like it might be equal to 1 if it's set, but I'm not sure)

Comment: Basically you don't you just use the php to show one bit if js to one group and another bit of js to the other. But, we're really getting into "new question" territory.

Comment: Thanks! And you're right - I'll post another question in order to figure that out :-)

Comment: Just wanted to share with you that I figured out how to use this to trigger the function I needed :-D I couldn't have done it without your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want, you shouldn't be mixing PHP and HTML code in the same file.

Most current frameworks use some kind of templating. If the user's logged in, show logged-in template. If he's not, show some other template.

There are many templating frameworks available for free, such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) (which is only used by Symfony).

If you don't feel like using these, you should consider splitting your code into different files, still, something like this:

```
<html>
[...]
    <body>
    [...]
        <?php 
            if (isset($_SESSION["SESS_USER_ID"])) {
                include("restricted_folder/file_i_want_my_logged_in_user_to_see.php");
            } else {
                include("login_required.php");
            }
        ?>
    [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

Just remember to make "restricted_folder" unavailable for direct access by your users, either removing access permissions (chmod'ing the folder should do it) or writing a .htaccess forbidding access to that folder.

Comment: Good to know :-) I'll definitely look into templates, but I'm not sure if I can get into them right now. Until then, I'd like to clarify what you wrote in the php. I've been setting a link from all secure pages to auth.php (which has if(isset... and redirects to another page if they're not logged in). 2 questions - How would you suggest that I combine this with Willoller's suggestion for the pages which don't necessarily require protection but where I need to change the user experience? Continuing below (due to character limitations :-))

Comment: I'm somewhat of a security noob so I could use some help understanding your suggestion about restricted folders and chmod'ing. I do have a .htaccess file set up, but I've relied upon my hosting company's security features until now for restricted folders, and I don't quite understand how to set that up (other than by restricting access to the specific files and redirecting them if $_SESSION["SESS_USER_ID"] isn't set)